# How do I add new text and variables to a .txt file

Tags: python, string, file, format

We're given a .txt file with 3 columns; name, height, and weight. We need to add a 4th column for BMI (from a given formula) as well as find the min, max, and average of each category.

The text is from a local file, "data.txt." Here's the text (made it in code block to keep formatting for printing it):

```
Name        Height(m)   Weight(kg)      
Joe         1.82        72.57       
Mary        1.60        63.50       
Dion        1.90        90.71       
Kayla       1.72        66.31       
Jose        1.78        70.23       
Sofia       1.63        65.12       
Erik        1.98        92.21       
Sara        1.57        65.77
```

Here's the code I have so far, that shows it mostly complete, except for the BMI column:

```
in_file = open("data.txt","r")
th=0 #total height
tw=0 #total weight
tbmi=0 #total bmi
min_h=3.00
min_w=100.00
min_bmi=40
max_h=0
max_w=0
max_bmi=0

for line_str in in_file:
    print(line_str,end="")
    if 'Heigh' not in line_str:
    a = float((line_str[12:16]))
    b = float((line_str[23:27]))
    bmi=(b/(a**2))
    tbmi+=bmi
    th += a
    tw +=b
    if min_h > a:
       min_h = a  
    if min_w > b:
        min_w = b
    if min_bmi > bmi:
        min_bmi = bmi
    if max_h < a:
        max_h =a
    if max_w < b:
        max_w =b
    if max_bmi < bmi:
        max_bmi = bmi
print("")
print('{:<12s}{:<12.2f}{:<12.2f}{:<12.2f}'.format("Average", th/8, tw/8, tbmi))
print('{:<12s}{:<12.2f}{:<12.2f}{:<12.2f}'.format("Max", max_h, max_w, max_bmi))
print('{:<12s}{:<12.2f}{:<12.2f}{:<12.2f}'.format("Min", min_h, min_w, min_bmi))
```

All I need to do is have a column with the header BMI,and all of the BMI values added to each line_str, but can't get anything to work, such as using readline() to ignore the first line, and I'd make my own header. I also can't print an independent header above the line "for line_str in in_file:" for some reason; in this case I was just going to make my own header, and then print off the results I needed line by line with the formatting I need. Seems inefficient...

Edit: The answer from Alessio did the trick! Wouldn't have thought of that!

Comment: It may be because you have opened the file in read mode. "in_file = open("data.txt","r")"

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get anything to work"?  Surely it prints something or gives you a traceback.

Comment: Sorry about that... Yes, It prints values that I need, such as the averages, etc. What won't work, is trying readline() to skip the first line of text and make my own header, or printing a new line above the text file (and then I was going to just print each value that I needed string by string with the correct formatting) but it won't let me print above "for line_str in in_file" for some reason

Comment: You can't use readline to discard the first line because `for line_str in in_file` always starts again from the beginning.  Like any for loop it is a new iteration:  `for i in range(10)` always begins with i=0 even if i was previously assigned to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this may be the solution you were looking for.
It prints the BMI column to the right of the other columns in the "result" variable. Once you ave it, you can do anything from writing it to a file or printing it to the console ( as I did :) ).
If you need to add other columns, just follow the example :)

```
in_file = open("data.txt","r")
th=0 #total height
tw=0 #total weight
tbmi=0 #total bmi
min_h=3.00
min_w=100.00
min_bmi=40
max_h=0
max_w=0
max_bmi=0

result = "Name        Height(m)   Weight(kg)  BMI\n"
for line_str in in_file:
    #print("TEST: " + line_str)
    if 'Height' not in line_str:
        a = float((line_str[12:16]))
        b = float((line_str[23:27]))
        bmi=(b/(a**2))
        result += line_str[0:len(line_str)-1] + '{:<12.2f}'.format(bmi) + "\n"
        tbmi+=bmi
        th += a
        tw +=b
        if min_h > a:
           min_h = a  
        if min_w > b:
            min_w = b
        if min_bmi > bmi:
            min_bmi = bmi
        if max_h < a:
            max_h =a
        if max_w < b:
            max_w =b
        if max_bmi < bmi:
            max_bmi = bmi

print(result)

print("")
print('{:<12s}{:<12.2f}{:<12.2f}{:<12.2f}'.format("Average", th/8, tw/8, tbmi))
print('{:<12s}{:<12.2f}{:<12.2f}{:<12.2f}'.format("Max", max_h, max_w, max_bmi))
print('{:<12s}{:<12.2f}{:<12.2f}{:<12.2f}'.format("Min", min_h, min_w, min_bmi))
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to deal with table-like files, I would always suggest you to use [*pandas*](http://pandas.pydata.org) in order to make your code cleaner and easier to extend.

What you want to achieve is easily done using the snippet below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\s+')
df["BMI"] = df["Weight(kg)"]/(df["Height(m)"] * df["Height(m)"])
print(df)
print(df.describe())
```

Output:

```
    Name  Height(m)  Weight(kg)        BMI
0    Joe       1.82       72.57  21.908586
1   Mary       1.60       63.50  24.804687
2   Dion       1.90       90.71  25.127424
3  Kayla       1.72       66.31  22.414143
4   Jose       1.78       70.23  22.165762
5  Sofia       1.63       65.12  24.509767
6   Erik       1.98       92.21  23.520559
7   Sara       1.57       65.77  26.682624

       Height(m)  Weight(kg)        BMI
count   8.000000    8.000000   8.000000
mean    1.750000   73.302500  23.891694
std     0.147067   11.583038   1.680321
min     1.570000   63.500000  21.908586
25%     1.622500   65.607500  22.352048
50%     1.750000   68.270000  24.015163
75%     1.840000   77.105000  24.885372
max     1.980000   92.210000  26.682624
```

Comment: That would certainly be an easier way! For this class right now, we have pretty strict parameters about what we can and cannot use. Pandas are something that sound familiar, as I believe we will be using them in the near future. This assignment, however, was mostly for using read and write, formatting, and really basic stuff like that. I can't wait until we can use more efficient stuff... Thanks!